# How do youmake a polygon shapped form that overlaps the header?

Tags: html, css

Need help on figuring out how to make this kind of form:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjuLS.png).

I know how to style the form with bootstrap but I can't figure out how to shape the container div. I also can't get it to overlap the header without having it move when I scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can have a look here, where CSS Shapes are declared:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes

But as you can see there, it's not supported in all browsers, so a better solution could be something like this:

Markup:

```
<header>Header</header>
<form>
  <label for="lastname">Lastname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  <br><br>
  <label for="firstname">Firstname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  height: 100px; 
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}
form {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: -10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
}

form::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 20px solid lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

form::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 70px solid lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  left: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/moritz-jaeger/pen/wXZNNP

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer!! do you have any suggestions on resources to learn these kinds of css things so I can get better at them? or anything you recommend to practice? thank you again!

Comment: also one more question. how come you can still see the form overlap on the header without using z-index? that is what i was trying to use

Comment: I've personally subscribed to various feeds (such as CSS tricks, scotch.io) that I read every morning and try out if possible. In addition, again and again very interesting and new features can be seen on codepen.
And what shouldn't be missing of course is the css-weekly newsletter, in which many interesting articles, new approaches and useful tips are in.

Comment: can you help me make this shape responsive?

Comment: updated my codepen. form and shape are more responsive now. Just play around with the form-wrapper width.

Answer (score 0):

For that learn how to create structure using css. Create a pentagon for it.

```css
#pentagon {
width: 100px;
height: 55px;
background: red;
position: relative;
  margin: 100px 0 0;
}

#pentagon:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -25px;
left: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="pentagon">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by learn how to create structures. do you know any good resources?